# Passing JavaScript Variable to PHP without page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, web-deployment

I'm trying to make a login page in which user gives all the traditional inputs
email, username, password and confirm password.
Everything works fine but am trying to check for a specific functionality

**Checking Whether Email id and username already existing or not and that too while im typing the email it should say whether already taken or not without page refresh and without any further clicks**

I remember seeing this feature on some websites

how i'm trying to achieve this

1)User gives input in the field  (achieved)

2)that input is capture by java using  document.getElementById("email_id").value    (achieved)

3)passing this value to PHP   (still trying tried with passing JS to PHP and cookies but unable to make it work)

4)now using that value checking in database whether email id already taken (Partially achieved)

here is the code:
(partial code which will be enough to test i think :) )

```
<form class="form_100" name="sign_up_form" action="includes/sign_up_sign_in_inc.php" method="post">
                    <table style="width:70%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group sign-up-divs">
                                    <input type="email" id="user_email_id_id"
                                        class="form-control password_match_valid password_match_invalid "
                                        onkeyup="email_id_validation()" name="user_email_id"
                                        aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email Address" required>
                                    <small id="emailHelp"
                                        class="form-text text-muted text_warning font_weight_600">We'll never
                                        share your email with anyone else.</small>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <img id="user_email_id_match_database" src="images\cross_mark.png"
                                    class="vertical_align">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                  </table>
             </form>
```

above code shows the form input field user email id and with a small cross mark (which will be tick when email id exists)

Java Script and php code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function email_id_validation() {
    var user_email_id_match_database_variable = document.getElementById("user_email_id_id").value;
    document.getElementById("demo22").innerHTML = user_email_id_match_database_variable;

    var echo_var = '<?php 
$user_email_id= "<script>
document.writeln(user_email_id_match_database_variable);
</script>";

$server_name="localhost";
$database_username="root";
$database_password="";
$database_name="creative_medicine";

$conn = mysqli_connect($server_name, $database_username, $database_password, $database_name);

if(!$conn){
die("connection failed:" .mysqli_connection_error());
}

$sql= "SELECT * FROM user_sign_up_details WHERE user_email_id = ?;";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql))
{
header("location: ../sign_up_sign_in.php?error=stmtfailed_sign_up_sign_in_inc_email_verification");
exit();
}
echo("here ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user_email_id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
$count_of_rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultData);
echo $count_of_rows;
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
?> ';



}
</script>
```

The main query is how can i pass value of js to php
i check many questions but ended up 3 answer

1)$user_email_id= "

```
<script>
    document.writeln(user_email_id_match_database_variable);
    </script>";
```

2)using cookies

3)few say its impossible stating that passing a value from front to back end and checking it is quite impossible as js runs on client side and php runs on server side

If u need any additional code or any other idea to achieve the same goal will be helpful please comment below(i have been trying this from past 2 days)

Comment: You need to use ajax method. (_and "how to indent"_)

Comment: @MisterJojo Achieved the requirement thanks a lot :)